# The type 'ImageConverter' exists in both

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In a Visual Studio Project this worked for a while

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
```

Even for that

```
System.Drawing.ImageConverter imgConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
```

Now Visual Studio Complains

```
CS0433  The type 'ImageConverter' exists in both 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=5.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Windows.Extensions, Version=4.0.1.0,
```

What is odd here is that there is no System.Drawing.Common.ImageConverter !

There is just a System.Drawing.ImageConverter and I have already added using System.Drawing at the using section

After adding

```
System.ServiceModel.Duplex
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
System.ServiceModel.Security
```

it seems to be not related and I have tried everything which I found about CS0433 with no solution so far. Any idea what have changed ? or what else could be tweaked to make clear I want to use explicitly System.Drawing.ImageConverter in a csharp project ?

Comment: Apparently your project has NuGet package references to `System.Drawing.Common` and to `System.Windows.Extensions`. Their versions are not compatible, if you can, update `System.Windows.Extensions` to 5.0 or update both to latest versions. If you do not need both get rid of the one you do not need.

Comment: Thanks, but looks like the System.ServiceModel stuff depends on System.Windows.Extensions which have no newer version

Comment: You could try to see if the functionality you need from `System.Drawing` is covered by `System.Windows.Extensions`. Also their seems to be a NuGet package for `System.ServiceModel` maybe you could add that? (And their are higher versions of `System.Windows.Extensions`, do you get your package from a private NuGet server?)

Comment: yes I get them all from nuget and I have all the latest versions. I wonder why an alias or a complete Namesspace.Package path does not work in that case

Comment: Could you replace `using System.Drawing` with `using System.Drawing.ImageConverter`? 
Because `System.Drawing.Common` is also included under `System.Drawing.Common`.
If it works, please let me know.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I have tested that before and it didn't help. Solution was installing Sys.Windows.Extensions in their latest version. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been solved by installing the latest Version of System.Windows.Extensions (5.0.0)

The issue has been raised and discussed with the core developers [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59807)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you just need a full qualified name like:

```
> byte[] bytes = (byte[])new
> System.Drawing.Common.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(bitmap,
> typeof(byte[]));
```

This will remove the ambiguity about which library you want to draw it from.

Comment: What is odd that there is no System.Drawing.Common.ImageConverter. There is just a System.Drawing.ImageConverter. Will change the question for that

Comment: oh and still with your change VS 2019 is complaining the same for me

Comment: The name of the package does not mean necessarily that all the namespaces will include it. In System.Drawing.Common. Are you sure you need both System.Drawing.Common and System.Windows.Extensions NuGets?

Comment: Where Do you see that I have Importet System.Windows.Extensions ? The odd thing here is that VS 2019 is complaining about it where it is not imported